# How to write a conditional if else in join clause in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a update query like following -

```
UPDATE s
    SET    s.Column1 = NVS.Column1,
           s.Column2 = NVS.Column2,
           s.Column3 = NVS.Column3
    FROM   #Table1 s WITH(nolock)
           INNER JOIN Table2 NVS
                  on s.Column6 = NVS.Column7 and NVS.RN = 1 and ISNULL(s.Column4, s.Column5) >= NVS.Column6 
    where s.Column8 not in ('TestColumnName')
```

How do I create a query to use NVS.RN <> 1 when ISNULL(s.Column4, s.Column5) < NVS.Column6 condition?

Comment: `case when [condition] then [value] else [value] end`

Comment: Why are you using `NOLOCK` against a temporary table, *and* when it's the target of an `UPDATE`. That is a **terrible** idea. That strongly suggests you have no idea what the hint dose, and thus I strongly recommend you stop using it, and remove it from your other SQL until you learn what is *really* does.

Comment: Jorge Campos - how do I do it in the join condition? Not sure how to do that.

Comment: You would need a (properly grouped) OR clause to handle the two alternate cases. Try: on s.Column6 = NVS.Column7
and (
 (NVS.RN = 1 and ISNULL(s.Column4, s.Column5) >= NVS.Column6)
 or (NVS.RN <> 1 and ISNULL(s.Column4, s.Column5) < NVS.Column6)
 )

Comment: The Or condition doesn't work. I might end up creating a temp table and joining on the two conditions.

Comment: What are the values for NVS.RN, s.Column4, s.Column5, and NVS.Column6 where you are getting the unexpected result?  did you include all of the parentheses? Could the conditions be yielding more than one match between #table1 and table2?

Comment: Yes. Its parentheses are added correctly.

Comment: The way to "debug" `UPDATE` statements is to turn them into `SELECT *` statements and inspect the results. You can then easily try things without affecting the table and you can actually see how the columns are matched.